# Python module "requests" returns different variable type in python version 3 and 2

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I'm trying to get a hashed image file with the requests model in python, but am encountering problems when switching from python 2 to python 3.

`type(r.content)` in python 2 returns: `<type 'str'>`

but

`type(r.content)` in python 3 returns `<class 'bytes'>`

How can I get the same data in python 3 that I would normally get in python 2?

Comment: `bytes` is just the Python 3 equivalent of `str` (Python 3's `str` is 2's `unicode`).  The change in the name of the type shouldn't make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

You have to decode the `bytes` object in order to get a `str`. Something like `bytes.decode('utf-8')`, just with the right encoding.

```
>>> a.decode('utf-8')
'asd'
>>> x = b'Hello'
>>> type(x)
<class 'bytes'>
>>> y = x.decode('utf-8')
>>> y
'Hello'
>>> type(y)
<class 'str'>
```